# one key multiple values in HashMap using object

Tags: java, hashmap

if I want "id" is key and "name", "phoneNumber", "eamil" are values.

```
public class Personal {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private String email;

    public Personal(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getter and setter here
}
```

after input many person data. I can get data by id.

```
output ex: map.get(100001); // [Dan, 123456, Dan@gmail.com]
           map.get(100002); // [Kim, 123343, Kim@gmail.com] 
           ...
```

Question: What's the best ways to implement this HashMap ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with using `HashMap<Integer, Personal>`, and putting your instances of Personal class into the map?

Comment: Just a little be confuse, I think I already get a answer. THANKS :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the IDs are unique and set in stone, you could use:

```
Map<Integer,Personal> map = new HashMap<Integer,Personal>();
```

To add an object `p`:

```
map.put(p.getId(), p);
```

Then

```
map.get(100001);
```

would return the corresponding object.

If the IDs can repeat or can change, things get more complicated. If that's the case, please explain your exact requirements so that we can help further.